# Is there a command to query how many chunks make up a given world? (v1.15.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

**Version:** Minecraft Java Edition, 1.15.2, server

Is there a [console command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands), or area on the [Debug screen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_screen), for querying how many total, already been generated and stored chunks which make up the entire current Minecraft world?

I know there are [Minecraft Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) around querying for on chunks which are *currently loaded*, but not total generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own Question, there ***isn't*** [a vanilla Minecraft Command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) to retrieve the total chunks that have already been generated by the *server.jar*.

There is, however, [MCA Selector](https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector#mca-selector). It's a tool which can be used to edit a Minecraft world with a top-down view. [MCA Selector](https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector#mca-selector) also has a readout of block and chunk coordinates which can be used to derive the area of chunks generated previously.

Answer (score 1):

For an upper bound, you can look at your Minecraft data folders, specifically in your world folder in `saves` the folders `region`, `DIM-1/region` and `DIM1/region`. Each file in those contains up to 32×32 chunks, so your maximum is 1024 times the number of files there.

For more details, you could use [NBTExplorer](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac). It shows you all the chunks that are actually contained in these files. But that's a very manual process, so the other answer is probably better.